# How can i scroll a overflow div with Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, overflow

How can i scroll down a overflow div with Selenium (Java)? I dont want to scroll the browser window but within an div element.

I tested

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;        
jse.executeScript("getElementByXpath('/html/body/div[2]').scrollBy(0, 1800)");
```

but it didnt worked out.

im using webdriver.gecko.driver on a mac

Comment: 1. please add source code of the html 2. do you get any exception? If yes, what exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code :-

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]"));
we.sendKeys(Keys.END);
```

OR

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]"));
we.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,
Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Comment: He don't want to scroll the window.